# mysql query - In a table, if a date exist return record else return previous date's record

Tags: mysql, sql

If user input date is `2021-08-08` (date present in table), it should return records having this date. If user input date is `2021-08-07` (date not present in table), it should return records `2021-08-05` for the date (previous available date).

Sample data:

[image: dummy_table for more details]

Comment: Not sure where the downvote came from, but it probably has to do with posting the sample data as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from `MyTable`
where targetdate = (
    select targetdate 
    from `MyTable`
    where targetdate <= @UserInput
    order by targetdate desc
    limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_column <= @date_input
ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

If more than one row matches the date then indefinite one of them will be returned. If you need some definite then you must describe this precisely.